# Can we convert light to another spectrum?

Tags: visible-light

Could we convert light from one spectrum to another just like how it does in a radium, using some device?

If we could do that to a specific part of the emitted light, probably we could make 3-D holograms.

Comment: "like how it does in a radium"? How it does in a radium?

Comment: There are some certain phosophors who concert U.V light to visible light

Comment: And of which spectrum you speak? The spectral lines of some type of atom to the spectral lines of another type of atom?

Comment: If we could convert U.V to Visible light surely would be amazing.

Comment: I know that by the down-conversion process (is it known to you?) you can split an U.V. photon into two photons from which at least one can be in the visible range. Also, the Compton effect, which means scattering of photons, imparts the initial photon energy from atom to atom, and the initial photon remains with a lower and lower frequency. Does that answer to you?

Comment: Yes? What is so amazing about that?

Comment: It is a simple process, currently used.

Comment: How is this done exactly?

Comment: Its delighting to know We can do such.

Comment: Is there a way to do convert I.R waves to Visible light.

Comment: The Compton scattering is quite trivial, see the explanation in the Wikipedia, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compton_scattering . About the down-conversion, it is of two types, stimulated or spontaneous. I believe that you are interested in the spontaneous. What you do is the send the U.V. beam on a certain type of crystal, usually a BBO crystal, and what gets out are pairs of photons, and in each pair is is likely that one of the photons is in visible. See explanation in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_parametric_down-conversion.

Comment: I read about this conversion.The up conversion is more efficient.While the down conversion , splits one photon in a billion chances.What I would like to know, Using a Ir transmitter could we produce Visible light and use it as a bulb.How efficient is that? What are the limitations.

Comment: Wow! You probably will be pleased: here is what I see in Google. Up-conversion is possible, http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0927024807000529

Comment: This is cool : )

Comment: I read about the converters , as I mentioned in previous post upconversion has more efficiency.This link talks about the utilization of rare earyh phosophors to do conversion

Comment: What would be useful is if we could understand how these phosophors work and replicate their working with a cheaper cost, if we could make bulbs through conversion : )

Comment: It's already not my domain. So, try to read the articles, and then ask another question. But beware, the community rejects engineering questions, useful and interesting as they might be. So, pay much attention how you formulate your question, so as not to be an engineering question.